# How to get snapshot from video memorystream or byte[] using FFmpegCore instead of file path?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream

I am trying to get snapshots from video data that can be in a MemoryStream OR Byte[] but not located on physical file path. FFMpegCore provide option to use Arguments with PipeSource but not sure how to use it. I have updated code for taking snapshot from Stream as below but it gives

```
public static async Task<Bitmap> SnapshotAsync(Stream input, IMediaAnalysis source, Size? size = null, TimeSpan? captureTime = null, int? streamIndex = null, int inputFileIndex = 0)
    {
        input.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        FFMpegCore.Pipes.StreamPipeSource streamPipeSource = new FFMpegCore.Pipes.StreamPipeSource(input);
        var (arguments, outputOptions) = BuildSnapshotArguments(streamPipeSource, source, size, captureTime, streamIndex, inputFileIndex);
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();

        await arguments
            .OutputToPipe(new StreamPipeSink(ms), options => outputOptions(options
                .ForceFormat("rawvideo")))
            .ProcessAsynchronously().ConfigureAwait(false);

        ms.Position = 0;
        return new Bitmap(ms);
    }

    private static (FFMpegArguments, Action<FFMpegArgumentOptions> outputOptions) BuildSnapshotArguments(
        IPipeSource input,
        IMediaAnalysis source,
        Size? size = null,
        TimeSpan? captureTime = null,
        int? streamIndex = null,
        int inputFileIndex = 0)
    {
        captureTime ??= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(source.Duration.TotalSeconds / 3);
        size = PrepareSnapshotSize(source, size);
        streamIndex ??= source.PrimaryVideoStream?.Index
                        ?? source.VideoStreams.FirstOrDefault()?.Index
                        ?? 0;

        return (FFMpegArguments
            .FromPipeInput(input, options => options
                 .Seek(captureTime)),
            options => options
                .SelectStream((int)streamIndex, inputFileIndex)
                .WithVideoCodec(VideoCodec.Png)
                .WithFrameOutputCount(1)
                .Resize(size));
    }
   
    private static Size? PrepareSnapshotSize(IMediaAnalysis source, Size? wantedSize)
    {
        if (wantedSize == null || (wantedSize.Value.Height <= 0 && wantedSize.Value.Width <= 0) || source.PrimaryVideoStream == null)
            return null;

        var currentSize = new Size(source.PrimaryVideoStream.Width, source.PrimaryVideoStream.Height);
        if (source.PrimaryVideoStream.Rotation == 90 || source.PrimaryVideoStream.Rotation == 180)
            currentSize = new Size(source.PrimaryVideoStream.Height, source.PrimaryVideoStream.Width);

        if (wantedSize.Value.Width != currentSize.Width || wantedSize.Value.Height != currentSize.Height)
        {
            if (wantedSize.Value.Width <= 0 && wantedSize.Value.Height > 0)
            {
                var ratio = (double)wantedSize.Value.Height / currentSize.Height;
                return new Size((int)(currentSize.Width * ratio), (int)(currentSize.Height * ratio));
            }
            if (wantedSize.Value.Height <= 0 && wantedSize.Value.Width > 0)
            {
                var ratio = (double)wantedSize.Value.Width / currentSize.Width;
                return new Size((int)(currentSize.Width * ratio), (int)(currentSize.Height * ratio));
            }
            return wantedSize;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

it is giving error under SnapShotAsync function at this line

```
await arguments
            .OutputToPipe(new StreamPipeSink(ms), options => outputOptions(options
                .ForceFormat("rawvideo")))
            .ProcessAsynchronously().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

here is full error message

> ffmpeg exited with non-zero exit-code (1 - ffmpeg version 2021-04-04-git-b1b7cc698b-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
> built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
> libavutil      56. 72.100 / 56. 72.100
> libavcodec     58.135.100 / 58.135.100
> libavformat    58. 77.100 / 58. 77.100
> libavdevice    58. 14.100 / 58. 14.100
> libavfilter     7.111.100 /  7.111.100
> libswscale      5. 10.100 /  5. 10.100
> libswresample   3. 10.100 /  3. 10.100
> libpostproc    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001c78845f040] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 4716 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
> Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '\.\pipe\FFMpegCore_4599336d-fbf8-430e-ab89-19082c7d3693':
> Metadata:
> major_brand     : mp42
> minor_version   : 0
> compatible_brands: mp41isom
> creation_time   : 2021-11-17T11:53:33.000000Z
> Duration: 00:00:03.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 4716 kb/s, 15.20 fps, 15.08 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
> Metadata:
> creation_time   : 2021-11-17T11:53:33.000000Z
> handler_name    : VideoHandler
> vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
> encoder         : AVC Coding
> Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 170 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> creation_time   : 2021-11-17T11:53:33.000000Z
> handler_name    : SoundHandler
> vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
> Stream mapping:
> Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
> Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> \.\pipe\FFMpegCore_4599336d-fbf8-430e-ab89-19082c7d3693: Invalid argument
> Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
> Error marking filters as finished
> Conversion failed!)

I am just passing a video file

```
    using (Stream fms = File.OpenRead(txtVideoPath.Text))
            {
                fms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (MemoryStream vms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    fms.CopyTo(vms);
                    vms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
--pass vms to snapshot function
                    ....
                }
            }
```

is there any way to get snapshot from stream without storing file physically ?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but did you find your answer? I ran into a similar issue.